# How to add two or more Target id under 'Id' : instance id in aws lambda function with python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, devops

I want to register/deregister two ec2 instance which is i-26377gdhdhj and i-9876277sgshj in aws alb target group using lambda function python script.

I want to know how to add both instance id under Targets id simultaneously.Please help.

This is my current script.

```
import boto3

clients=boto3.client('elbv2')

response_tg = clients.register_targets(
    TargetGroupArn='arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:123456789123:targetgroup/target-demo/c64e6bfc00b4658f',
    Targets=[
       {
        'Id': 'i-26377gdhdhj',
       },
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
response_tg = clients.register_targets(
    TargetGroupArn='arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:123456789123:targetgroup/target-demo/c64e6bfc00b4658f',
    Targets=[
       {
        'Id': 'i-26377gdhdhj',
       },
       {
        'Id': 'i-9876277sgshj',
       }
    ]
)
```

Since `Targets` is a list, you can pass them both in.

Comment: i am facing a chalenge if one of the given ec2 instance id is wrong then test run under lambda is not working and error ( i-9876277sgshj) is not in running state.                                                       So if an ec2 instance id was wrong why didn't it registere the correct ec2 instance .please help if any ec2 instance id is wrong it will skip it and register correct ec2 instance.  And how can i get the result of the script when it executed.

Comment: Since it is one operation to "register_targets" that takes a list as an input it needs to either succeed or fail as a whole--like a transaction.  Documentation says "If the target is an EC2 instance, it must be in the running state when you register it." If I am misunderstanding the question/issue, you may want to pose a new question with the details to get better inputs.